# Нахождение среднего арифметического

Tags: c++, c

Как сделать просто программу для вычисления среднего арифметического знаю, а как сделать эту непонятно

> Использовать тип с плавающей запятой длиной 32 бита (`float`,
>   `single`) для нахождения среднего арифметического `F(8+30)` 10000
>   значений. `F(x)=sin(x)cos(x)` Для вычисления создайте программу на
>   произвольном (любом) языке программирования и произведите расчеты:
>
> - а) Сложить в цикле 10000 раз значения `F(8+1)`, результат разделить на количество слагаемых 10000, записать полученный результат.
> - б) Сложить в цикле 10000 раз значения `F(8+1)/10000`, результат записать.
> - в) Зная точный результат среднего арифметического (складываются одинаковые числа 10000 раз, и результат делится на 10000, потому
>     результат должен быть равным значению `F(N+1)`), найти относительную и
>     абсолютную погрешность вычислений

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То есть, это проблема написать код вида

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
#define NUM 10000

float f(float x)
{
    return sin(x) * cos(x);
}

float v1(float a)
{
    float r = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        r += f(a);
    }
    return r / NUM;
}

float v2(float a)
{
    float r = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        r += f(a) / NUM;
    }
    return r;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    float arg = 30e-8;
    float r1 = v1(arg);
    float r2 = v2(arg);
    float r3 = f(arg);

    std::cout << "r1 = " << r1 << "\nr2 = " << r2 << "\nr3 = " << r3 << std::endl;
    float d1 = (r3-r1)/r3 * 100;
    float d2 = (r3-r2)/r3 * 100;
    std::cout << "error1 = " << d1 << "%\nerror2 = " << d2 << "%" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

(в коде есть странная вещь вида 8+30, N+1. Я думаю, это просто недописанная форма экспотенциальной записи)

Comment: интересно, минус за то что написал код?

Comment: вообще ничего не ставил, спасибо за ответ(P.S. как тут вообще ставить что либо тому кто ответил?) Все нашел, поставил плюс. А я не могу поставить, там нужно 15 баллов иметь(((

Comment: Минус был с флагом, больше нету.